# iOS PhoneGap Build Failure

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am new to `PhoneGap` for iOS and Xcode.  I am having an issue with my app that worked on Android phones just fine.  I'm able to build and run the app in the iOS simulator but when I archive it to test on devices I get the error below.  I've searched all over and cannot find something that works.

Error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/danlehman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-ebkivbdaivqchkgycifnnpgixspn/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/HelloWorld/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/danlehman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-ebkivbdaivqchkgycifnnpgixspn/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/HelloWorld/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVURLProtocol", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the guys at PhoneGap are trying to get v.3 out so they can debut it at a conference mid July 2013.  It appears they are on a rather rapid release schedule, which is kind of frustrating as I have found some errors with things as simple as the Splash Screen not working, etc.  Oh well.  The suggestion below (regarding checking out the latest 2.9.x branch) worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

I was getting a similar error for **Cordova 2.7**, Xcode 5 and iOS7 building on iPhone 4S. I changed one setting, and it built correctly.

Select your app. 
Go to **Build Settings** then **Valid Architectures**.
Change to:

```
armv7
```

My previous setting was:

```
arm64 armv7 armv7s
```

Clean and build. It seems to be related to **armv7s**. One side effect of getting it running is that the status bar is transparent and floating on top of the app. That is another topic though, and related to iOS7.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this and read through countless "solutions" that seemed to work for some but not me. With that in mind, *this might not work for you.* :)

1) Clone the cordova-ios repo

*git clone git@github.com:apache/cordova-ios.git*

2) Look at available branches

*git branch -a*

You'll probably see something like:

- master
  remotes/origin/0.9.5.1
  remotes/origin/0.9.6.x
  remotes/origin/1.6.1
  remotes/origin/1091
  remotes/origin/2.6.x
  remotes/origin/2.7.x
  remotes/origin/2.8.x
  remotes/origin/2.9.x
  remotes/origin/3.0.0
  remotes/origin/464
  remotes/origin/CB-3530
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/better_resource_copy_step
  remotes/origin/custom_schemes
  remotes/origin/device
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/multipart_plugin_result
  remotes/origin/next
  remotes/origin/phonegap-js

3) I built my app with Cordova 2.9 so checkout the 2.9.x branch -- adjust for your project

*git checkout -b 2.9.x origin/2.9.x*

4) Verify you are on the desired branch

*git branch*

You should see something like:

- 2.9.x
  master

5) Go into bin/

*cd bin/*

6) Now recreate the cordova app:

*./create ~/some/project/dir/project com.project project*

7) Copy your www folder from the failing build to the new project.

8) Get successful build message from Xcode.

9) Give Xcode the finger.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 - you are a saint sir.  Thanks for laying out all the commands for less-experienced users.  While the above instructions seem intimidating, it took me less than 5 minutes - clone repo, checkout branch, create new project, copy www folder.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Hopefully you followed step 9 as it's the most important. :)

Comment: Yeah, XCode and iAmSoCool device development has it's own set of issues - which I wont get into here.  Unfortunately, this one is on the guys at PhoneGap.

Answer (score 1):

This is an error in Phonegap.  You need to go to build settings in the project, search for "Other Linker Flags", then change:

Change "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/libCordova.a"

to

"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libCordova.a"